# Laravel/dropzone - TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am trying to setup a dropzone image file upload in my Laravel 5.3 app, but whenever I try to upload an image I get a above mentioned error. I am sending a csrf_token in my script like this, so not sure why I get this error?

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
     url: "/admin/upload",
     params: {
        _token: token
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps, I hope that will solve your problem..

Add this line into your `head` tag section

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

and then add these lines before your `</body>` end/closing section.

```
var csrf_token   =   $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrf_token}
});
```

so, after doing above steps, you dont need to send token into your dropzone ajax request. eg

```
 params: {
        _token: token // dont need this line after following above steps
 }
```